# why is "if @user.save" used in this way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, railstutorial.org

I'm working through the Michael Hartl's rails book, and I'm curious how this works:

```
if @user.save 

else

end
```

In if statements, the argument doesn't actually do anything much besides return true or false.

This method seems to save the model to the database and then return true or false. Is this common/am I right? Why do we do it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the `if @user.save` is checking if the object was successfully saved to the database using ActiveRecord.  From there you could do something like set a flash message and redirect somewhere.  In the `else` clause you could potentially inspect the `@user.errors` to see what went wrong and deal with it.

Example:

```
def create
  #Set user object attributes using strong parameters
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  #Attempt to save @user
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = 'User saved successfully'
    redirect_to somewhere_else_url
  else
    #Saving failed, we can inspect @user.errors for more information
    flash[:alert] = 'User was not saved.'

    #If using a form library @user.errors will be displayed graphically when rendering the :new action
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: but it seems to me that if @user.save is doing the saving as well -- it saves the model to the database and then returns true

Comment: Correct.  `@user.save` will save the object and return true ONLY if it saves without errors, if there were errors, it returns false.  This allows you to write logic based on whether the database save was successful or not.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save

Comment: I guess I'm just more used to if statements where the argument is just a variable that stores true or false

Comment: No reason you can't check a method return in a conditional block.

Comment: do you mind giving a quick example? I'm having trouble seeing how I could do that in this case since if I just add another @user.save at the beginning it feels pretty pointless

Comment: @JeffBurghess added an example for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to Michael Hartl, as it is described in Chapter 6, The **save** method returns true if it succeeds and false otherwise.

Therefore **save** method will succeed if there are no erros(like validations) and store the user model in database otherwise the method will end and return false.

You can refer chapter 6 [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users) and check the section 6.1.3.

Comment: This is premium content that you have to pay for, and not something that is useful to link to on stackoverflow.